# slurm - run multiple R scripts in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, batch-processing, slurm

Let's suppose I have 10 `.R` scripts (or tasks) that I wish to run all at the same time using an HPC cluster.

The HPC cluster uses `slurm` as a batching/queueing system and I know that for running multiple tasks I should use the command `srun`.

However, I do not have any experience with running multiple tasks in parallel with an HPC, so I hope you can help me setting up a simple `job.sh` script to be submitted via `slurm` to the HPC.

Here's an example of a job.sh script that I use for running a *single* `.R` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --partition=part_x
#SBATCH --nodelist=node888
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=45000
#SBATCH --output=node888.out
#SBATCH --error=node888.err
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=email@domain.hpc

Rscript /my/dir/script_1.R
```

How can I set-up a `job.sh` script that runs in parallel my 10 `.R` scripts named: script_1.R, script_2.R, script_3.R, script_4.R, ...., script_10.R?

Thanks for any help

Comment: you can either run them in background (by appending `&` at the end) or you can create a wrapper scripts `wrapper.sh` and start it with `mpirun`. Inside `wrapper.sh` (depending on process rank) you can start different script.

Comment: thank you @Oo.oO could you provide an answer with an example?

Comment: also...if I append & at the end of the .R scripts it works but as soon as one .R script ends the whole job.sh script stops, while other .R scripts are still running..

Answer (score 0):

To run in the Background:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="script_"

for iter in {1..10}
do

  mkdir $name$iter
  cd $name$iter
  cp ../$name$iter.R .
  nohup sbatch ./$name$iter.R &
  cd ../

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have number of scripts (`script_1`, `script_2`, `script_3`).

What you can do is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --partition=part_x
#SBATCH --nodelist=node888
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=45000
#SBATCH --output=node888.out
#SBATCH --error=node888.err
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=email@domain.hpc

mpirun -np NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES wrapper.sh
```

and then, inside `wrapper.sh`, you can do following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# depending on your installation, you have to get env var that tells you what
# process number it is

PROC_ID=${HERE_GOES_YOUR_SYSTEM_SPECIFIC_VARIABLE_WITH_RANK}

Rscript /my_scripts/script_${PROC_ID}.R
```

Of course, it makes sense as long as you properly allocate resources by specifying `--ntasks`, number of reserved nodes, etc. However, this may vary depending on target installation.